# DRF , route a retrieve function to a post function

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, routes

I have a Django rest framework API that gets a POST request and has a retrive method in the view.

I want that when the user presses the post button it will route the URL to the render created in the retrieve method of the view class.

code:

```py
#views.py


class LocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # Order all objects by id, reversed.
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method is used to get the last object created by the user and render a map associated with the
        mission's name.
        """

        data = self.queryset[0]
        serialized_data = LocationInfoSerializer(data, many=False)
        points = list(serialized_data.data.values())

        assign_gdt1 = GeoPoint(lat=points[2], long=points[3])
        assign_gdt2 = GeoPoint(lat=points[4], long=points[5])
        assign_uav = GeoPoint(lat=points[6], long=points[7], elevation=points[-3])

        # Geo locations from the POST request.
        gdt1 = [assign_gdt1.get_lat(), assign_gdt1.get_long()]
        gdt2 = [assign_gdt2.get_lat(), assign_gdt2.get_long()]
        uav = [assign_uav.get_lat(), assign_uav.get_long(), assign_uav.get_elevation()]

        mission_name = points[1]

        try:
            # Check if a file already exists in the DB.
            HTMLFileInteractionWithDB.table = THREE_POINTS_TRINAGULATION
            openfile = HTMLFileInteractionWithDB.return_file_from_db(mission_name=mission_name)
            return render(request, openfile)
        except:
            # Create a new file if one does not exists.
            # The main function Creates an HTML File to be rendered.
            return render(request, main(gdt1, gdt2, uav,
                                        gdt1_elev=assign_gdt1.get_elevation(),
                                        gdt2_elev=assign_gdt2.get_elevation(),
                                        mission_name=mission_name
                                        )
                          )
```

mission name is a primary key, So to access to the retrieve method the user need to go to the URL line and write the mission name for the method to work.

So, how and where in my project (urls,view...) do I create this route.

Exmpale:

[image: example]

Comment: Why to achieve routing in rest-apis? Sounds Weird!
Instead you can send the custom response you want to user when the post request is done..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to the purpose of this view.

The `retrieve` method is correctly used when it is retrieving a specific object from the queryset list using the pk. IE, one of your LocationInfo objects. It's always a get request.

Your retrieve method is also missing the pk parameter, which is sometimes defaulted as None.
`retrieve(self, request, pk=None)`

If I were you, I'd create a completely separate view or viewset method/action for this.

Instead of using `retrieve` for this, we can create a completely new method:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action

class LocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # Order all objects by id, reversed.
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer

    # {The rest of your methods, etc...}

    @action(detail=False, methods=["post"])
    def last_object_by_user(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your query to get the last object by your user
        queryset = LocationInfo.objects.filter(created_by=request.user).latest()
        # The rest of your code
```

This will create a new endpoint called /{name}/last_object_by_user/ that you can make post requests to.

You'd also notice that I've modified your queryset a bit. Your current queryset gives us the last LocationInfo created by any user. Did you create a field in LocationInfo that tracks who created that LocationInfo?

Here's the documentation for this: [Marking extra actions for routing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Note: I did not test this code so if you copy-paste this, it might not work, but the idea is what's important.